# C++: From stringstream to char**

Tags: c++, string, stdvector, stringstream

I have a class with `parse(int argc, char* argv[])` function which I have to use to set a desired state of an object. I'm taking the parameters from the gui using `stringstream` and then I'm trying to convert them to char** to pass them to the function. Here's what I've got:

```
std::stringstream sstream;

sstream << "-clip" << " " << min_x_entry.get_text()
        << " " << max_x_entry.get_text(); // etc.

std::cout << sstream.str();    // All looks good here

std::vector<std::string> args;
std::vector<char*> argv;
std::string arg;

while (sstream >> arg)
{
    args.push_back(arg);
    argv.push_back(const_cast<char*>(args.back().c_str()));
}
argv.push_back(0);

int argc = args.size();

for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    std::cout << &argv[0][i];    // This outputs garbage

my_object.parse(argc, &argv[0])  // And this fails
```

What am I missing? Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: `sstream >> arg` will not work with quotes or escaped spaces... but if you don't need it, then fine. Now, what do you think is the type of `&argv[0][i]`? It outputs address, not value...

Comment: I don't need quotes and I assume Gtk::Entry::get_text() doesn't add any escape characters.

Comment: By "escaped space" I mean that magical `\ ` you can use in Unix terminals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A problem would be reallocation of the `args` vector as [`push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) will grow the size of the vector if required:

> If new size() is not larger than capacity(), no iterators or references are invalidated. **Otherwise all iterators and references are invalidated.**

The `argv` vector is storing pointers to the internals of elements in `args`, so these would be invalidated.

A solution would be to create the `args` vector first then create the `argv` vector afterwards:

```
while (sstream >> arg) args.push_back(arg);

for (auto i = args.begin(); i != args.end(); i++)
{
    argv.push_back(const_cast<char*>(i->c_str()));
}
argv.push_back(0);
```

The `for` loop that prints out the `argv` strings is incorrect. This:

```
&argv[0][i]
```

is a `char*` but starts from `i`th element of the first entry in `argv`. For example, if the first c-string in `argv` was `"string"`:

```
&argv[0][1] is "tring"
&argv[0][2] is "ring"
```

change to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl; // Added 'endl' to flush 'cout'.
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. If I add `cout << i->c_str()` in the above loop it looks ok, but when I do `for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) { cout << &argv[0][i] }` after that I get nothing.

Comment: It still doesn't print for some reason. However it doesn't matter. It works now. All I needed was a dummy argument as the first element of argv array... Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Marian, I would recommend spending time investigating why this does not print: it should, see this for example http://ideone.com/Rx7qz . Note I added `std::endl;` to flush `cout`. Changing code and then observing it "working" and not understanding why is not a good way to program, and can often lead to depending on undefined behaviour (which sometimes appears to work). See http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence .

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<std::string> args;
std::vector<char*> argv;

/* ... */

    argv.push_back(const_cast<char*>(args.back().c_str()));
```

Many problems here.

1. The pointer returned by `c_str()` is not guaranteed to be valid after any subsequent call of a non-`const` member function of the same `string`.  The pointer returned from `c_str()` generally shouldn't be stored and used later, especially if you're not sure if other code will call a non-`const` member of the `string`.
2. You are `const_cast`ing the `const`-nedd away from the pointer returned by `c_str()`.  The cast itself is legal, if not an anti-pattern.  But if you then later try to *modify* the data stored at that pointer, that's Undefined Behavior.

Here is what the Standard has to say about `c_str()`:

### 21.3.6 basic_string string operations [lib.string.ops]

```
const charT* c_str() const;
```

> 1/ Returns: A pointer to the initial element of an array of length
>   size() + 1 whose first size() elements equal the corresponding
>   elements of the string controlled by *this and whose last element is a
>   null character specified by charT().
>
> 2/ Requires: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in
>   the array. Nor shall the program treat the returned value as a valid
>   pointer value after any subsequent call to a non-const member function
>   of the class basic_string that designates the same object as this.
>   const charT* data() const;
>
> 3/ Returns: If size() is nonzero, the member returns a pointer to the
>   initial element of an array whose first size() elements equal the
>   corresponding elements of the string controlled by *this. If size() is
>   zero, the member returns a non-null pointer that is copyable and can
>   have zero added to it.
>
> 4/ Requires: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in
>   the character array. Nor shall the program treat the returned value as
>   a valid pointer value after any subsequent call to a non- const member
>   function of basic_string that designates the same object as this.
>   allocator_type get_allocator() const;
>
> 5/ Returns: a copy of the Allocator object used to construct the
>   string.

Comment: No, argv[0] is char*, not std::string.

Comment: Is `std::string::c_str()` guaranteed to be valid as long as the `std::string` object is unchanged?

Comment: It is my understanding that argv[0] is char* thus &argv[0] is char**.

Comment: @Henrik:  Right, sorry, for some reason I thought I was looking at argc.  Edited/fixed.

Comment: @hmjd: It's guaranteed to be valid so long as you don't call a non-`const` string member function.  I'll edit with the appropriate Standard excerpt.

Comment: He could store the `c_str()` results, if he did it only after the `args` vector is fully constructed and not touched anymore. It's in fact the easiest solution.

Comment: @JohnDibling The pointer returned by `c_str()` doesn't point to a temporary; it points to memory owned by the `std::string` object, and has a lifetime guaranteed by the standard (but roughly, until you call a non-const function). _If_ you construct the the `args` array fully up front, the results of `c_str()` on its members is guaranteed for as long as you don't do anything with the `args` vector.

Comment: @JamesKanze:  I wasn't using "temporary" in the sense of a temporary variable.  I added the Std excerpt, and I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @JanHudec:  And also only if you don't try to modify the data pointed to by `c_str()`.  Since he's casting away `const`, this may well be happening.  I'd argue in any case that it's not the easiest solution.  The easiest solution is to just use a `vector<char>` and copy the contents.  Then you can do almost anything you want assuming you take care.

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to initialize the variable `i` in the loop. And You're trying to print out only the first item in the vector `argv`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    std::cout << argv[i];
```

Comment: It was a typo obviously. It wouldn't even compile otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of `const_cast` and not worry about `parse()` method possibly modifying the arguments by doing something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> args;

std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(sstream),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              [&args](const std::string& str)
              {
                  std::vector<char> temp(str.begin(), str.end());
                  temp.push_back('\0');
                  args.push_back(temp);
              });

std::vector<char*> argv(args.size());

for (auto& v : args) argv.push_back(v.data());

my_object.parse(argv.size(), argv.data());
```

Comment: The snippet is C++11. Replace `auto` with `std::vector<char>`. What about lambda function and range-based for?