# C++: Converting stringstream to char* runtime error

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am trying to convert in C++ a stringstream of "1.txt" so that it is equal to a char* value of "1.txt".  I need the raw char* as an argument for a function, so it can't be const char or anything else.  When I run it, I get a blank output.  Why, and how do I fix it?

```
#define SSTR(x) dynamic_cast< std::stringstream & >( (std::stringstream() << std::dec << x ) ).str()
int booknum = 1;
std::stringstream stringstream;
stringstream << SSTR(booknum) << ".txt";
std::vector<std::string> argv;
std::vector<char*> argc;
std::string arg;
std::string arg3;
while (stringstream >> arg) argv.push_back(arg);
for (auto i = argv.begin(); i != argv.end(); i++)
   argc.push_back(const_cast<char*>(i->c_str()));
argc.push_back(0);
int arg4 = argc.size();
for (int i = 0; i < arg4; i++)
    std::cout << &arg3[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: Do you always write like this or only for SO? Format your code, give sensible names to the variables and maybe someone will help you.

Comment: why do you go such length to just convert from one type to another?

Comment: I used the approach here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209311/c-from-stringstream-to-char

Comment: @EricMorse: I don't see anywhere on that page anything even remotely similar to your `SSTR` macro.

Comment: @Mooing Duck:  The easiest method to convert string to int since my compiler doesn't have the itoa command.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c/5590404#5590404

Comment: @EricMorse: Does it have `std::to_string`?

Comment: @Mooing Duck:  I get error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std' when doing #include <string> with std::string b = std::to_string(3);

Comment: oh I figured out what was wrong.  I wasn't using -std=c++11 when compiling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems very complicated, instead of e.g.

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << booknum << ".txt";
std::string s = oss.str();
char* pString = new char[s.length() + 1];
std::copy(s.c_str(), s.c_str() + s.length() + 1, pString);

yourFunctionThatTakesCharPtr(pString);

delete[] pString;
```

Comment: You could even replace `pString` with a `std::string`

Comment: @MooingDuck It depends on what the function does, as it's stated in the question that it takes a non-const pointer.

Comment: Then pass in `s.data()`.  Oh, you mean it could take a pointer by reference and `delete[]` `new[]` it again?  Always possible I suppose.

Comment: @MooingDuck I mean that the string inside a `std::string` object should be considered constant when using raw pointers, using non-constant C-style pointer allows the function to modify the string which might not work well with the `std::string` object. For example, what if the function truncates the string by setting the string terminator, that won't be reflected by the `std::string` object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample conversion code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <typeinfo>  //it's just to print the resultant type to be sure


int main() {int booknum=1;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << booknum<<"1.txt";
    char* x=new char[ss.str().length()+1];
    ss >> x;
    std::cout<<typeid(x).name();
return 0;}
```

Output:

```
Pc
```